# Scope of setlocale function?

Tags: php

I want to sort an array in php which contains german 'umlaute'. This does not seem to be an easy task for php. I found the following example on the web:

```
$oldLocale=setlocale(LC_COLLATE, "0");
setlocale(LC_COLLATE, 'de_DE.utf8');
usort($countrys, 'strcoll'); 
setlocale(LC_COLLATE, $oldLocale);
```

This is working as expected. My question now is, what is the scope of setlocale? Is it limited to the current function I am in, is it limited to my thread, my session or is it global?

I am afraid of creating race conditions, but I cannot find any other information on this than:

> The setlocale() function sets locale information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will be a global setting, it keeps set the last value while the script is running. It's not related to sessions, it's scope is the php process itself.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php

Comment: So the solution I posted can and will interfere with other scripts, if my client will use a multithreaded server? That would be bad news, thank you!

Comment: Yes, the exact note from php.net is: "The locale information is maintained per process, not per thread. If you are running PHP on a multithreaded server API like IIS, HHVM or Apache on Windows, you may experience sudden changes in locale settings while a script is running, though the script itself never called setlocale(). This happens due to other scripts running in different threads of the same process at the same time, changing the process-wide locale using setlocale()."